# how to select future date in date picker plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the jQuery Date Picker plugin. I want to give the user an ability to choose an date from the past (max 2 days). I tried the max date option, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any research or any codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the minDate and maxDate options, you can get any date period.

```
$("#myDatepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: "-2D" });
$("#myDatepicker2").datepicker({ minDate: "+2D" });
$("#myDatepicker3").datepicker({ minDate: "-2D", maxDate: 0 });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5546o0gx/2/)